# Help my MacBook Pro keeps crashing and I have no Idea why

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash

I have a 2015 Macbook Pro 13" Retina running 10.11.4 , which has been crashing every now and again and have no idea what sets it off. The last two times I was on Safari and the other I was happened while playing a game. I've saved the last two reports the machine sends to Apple after it boots up. I'm not sure if they're of any help, but any help would be appreciated!

http://pastebin.com/cAgzPJUf

http://pastebin.com/amPT8TUB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the crash is listed at the top of those reports:

> zalloc: zone map exhausted while allocating from zone buf.8192, likely due to memory leak in zone kalloc.256 (620851200 total bytes, 2420408 elements allocated)"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.40.184/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:2628

And this one:

> zalloc: zone map exhausted while allocating from zone ksyn_waitq_element, likely due to memory leak in zone kalloc.256 (733364224 total bytes, 2864697 elements allocated)"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.40.184/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:2628

It looks like a memory leak.  Further down the report is this:

> Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
>            **com.razer.common.razerhid**(15.38)[26748FCF-9967-378F-9E4D-4A77D1938E18]@0xffffff7f9ac6c000->0xffffff7f9ac86fff

It looks like it's being caused by a third-party driver, maybe a mouse or keyboard.  Check to see if there's any updated drivers.

Comment: Oh it's the mouse I got some time ago, unfortunately it says the software is up to date. So...I guess I'll just stop using the mouse, and contact their support people see if the can patch the problem. Thanks, I should've tried to just read the report, it just looks intimidating though.